# How make Axios "finally" waiting until "then" is finished?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to the **finally** be executed after the method **getCharacters** is finished, but without success.
He always is executed before.

There is a way to make him be executed after everything in the **then** is finished?

I suspect that the problem is the **axios** inside the **getCharacters** method.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
        return {
            message: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getCharacters() {
            axios
                .get('/api/messages/characters')
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('finish get')
                })
        },
        submitForm: function (event) {
            axios
                .post('/api/messages/send', {
                    message: this.message
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.getCharacters()
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    console.log('finish post')
                })
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the result of `getCharacters:`

```
            .then(response => {
                return this.getCharacters()
            })
```

or

```
            .then(response =>
                this.getCharacters()
            )
```

Comment: I put the return, but the console.log('finish get') still executing after the console.log('finish post').

Comment: The Promises need to be chained so your `getCharacters()` method must also `return axios.get(..)`